# MOOC's courses on Functional analysis

Tags: fa.functional-analysis

Several years ago, **Coursera** offered a MOOC (Massive Online Open Course) on Functional Analysis: 
*An Introduction to Functional Analysis. Taught by John Cagnol.
Ecole Centrale Paris.*

The duration was 8 weeks: 
1 Topology; continuity and convergence of a sequence in a topological space.
2 Metric and normed spaces; completeness.
3 Banach spaces; linear continuous functions; weak topology.
4 Hilbert spaces; The Riesz representation theorem.
5 The Lax-Milgram Lemma.
6 Properties of the Lp spaces.
7 Distributions and Sobolev Spaces.
8 Application: simulating a membrane.

Now it is possible to find the videos in the following **youtube** link:

https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLSpInro6Ys2IHve6oN9h005zmwfLnOSp1

However, the possibilities of doing short exams, asking questions, etc. are no longer available.

*Is there any comparable MOOC on Functional analysis currently active?*

Comment: MIT provides homework and solutions https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/18-102-introduction-to-functional-analysis-spring-2009/pages/assignments/